How to resolve TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable when calculating r2_score?
I am encountering the following error:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

when I try to calculate the R2 score using scikit-learn's r2_score function. Below is the relevant portion of my code:
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error

# Assuming Y is the actual values and ypipe is the predicted values
print('MSE for multi-variable polynomial pipeline is: ', mean_squared_error(Y, ypipe))
print('R^2 for multi-variable polynomial pipeline is: ', r2_score(Y, ypipe))


However, I receive the following error:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

enter image description here
This is also appearing when calculating r2_score for polynomial regression
enter image description here

I think you have a variable called r2_score in your notebook. That's why you got that error. To fix it, change the name of the variable r2_score to something like r2_result, then restart your notebook.

@auraham, thank you, that was very astute of you.
